# Calculate probabilities in bingo

Tags: probability, combinatorics

All cards have 5 columns and 3 rows (15 numbers) and we have 60 numbers in total but the extraction have 30 numbers.

I'm trying to solve a bingo problem that is : Determine the probability of hitting the first row (all 5 numbers) and not hitting the first and last column (at least one of that 4 numbers,because two of them hit in the first row, don't hit).

So i used combinations. 
I try this way :
$$ \frac {{{5}\choose{5}}*{{25}\choose{10}}-4*{{21}\choose{6}}}{{60}\choose{30}} $$
where 
$$ {25}\choose{10} $$ 
is the possibilities of put the 10 missing numbers on the card and 
$$ 4*{{21}\choose{6}}$$ 
because we don't want to hit 1 of the 4 numbers of the first and last column and the last numbers could be anyone.

I need change something or is this right ?
Thanks :)

Comment: By "hitting the first row" do you mean getting *at least one* of the number in the first row, or getting *all* the numbers in the first row?

Comment: getting all the numbers in the first row. I already edit for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability $P(A)$ of hitting the first row (all 5 numbers) is
$$P(A)=\frac{\binom{55}{25}}{\binom{60}{30}}$$
Given $A$, the probability $P(B)$ of hitting the other 4 numbers in the first and last columns is
$$P(B)=\frac{\binom{51}{21}}{\binom{55}{25}}$$
You want $P(A)\times(1-P(B))$
$$\frac{\binom{55}{25}}{\binom{60}{30}}\times\frac{\binom{55}{25}-\binom{51}{21}}{\binom{55}{25}}=\frac{\binom{55}{25}-\binom{51}{21}}{\binom{60}{30}}$$

Comment: How the probability P(A) could be that? We only have 15 numbers ( 5 columns and 3 rows in the card ).
And why $$ {55} \choose {25} $$? We are using numbers from the extraction that is 30 .

Comment: Of the 30 numbers drawn, 5 of them must be the numbers in the first row. The other 25 will be chosen from the 55 numbers not in the first row.

Comment: Now i understood . thank you !